# Blazor | Erro Registro do serviço - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

Olá,

Estou dando os primeiros passos no Blazor e seguindo um exemplo que vi na internet, que faz o Load do Menu e SubMenu direto do banco de dado, estou tendo problema na hora da compilação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O projeto está dividido desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente injetei o **MenuInfoService** no código na NavMenu.razor do projeto client:

```
@using FirstBlazorFinal.Shared.Services
@using FirstBlazorFinal.Shared.Models

@inject MenuInfoService MenuInfoService



<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">FirstBlazorFinal</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
@if (menuList == null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            @foreach (var menu in menuList)
            {
                @if (menu.ParentMenuId == 0)
                {
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@menu.PageMenu" @onclick="()=>GetIsClicked(menu)">
                            <span class="@menu.IconName" aria-hidden="true"></span>@menu.MenuName
                        </NavLink>

                        <ul class="nav flex-column">
                            @foreach (var subMenu in menuList)
                            {
                                @if (menu.MenuId == subMenu.ParentMenuId)
                                {
                                    @if (expandSubMenu && menu.MenuId == clickedMenu)
                                    {
                                        <li class="nav-item px-3">
                                            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@subMenu.PageMenu" @onclick="()=>GetIsClicked(subMenu)">
                                                <span class="@subMenu.IconName" aria-hidden="true"></span>@subMenu.MenuName
                                            </NavLink>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    }

</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
    private bool expandSubMenu;
    private int clickedMenu = 0;
    private bool hasPageName = true;
    private int prevClickedMenu = 0;

    public IEnumerable<MenuInfo> menuList;


    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        if (hasPageName)
        {
            collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
        }
    }

    public void GetIsClicked(MenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        clickedMenu = menuInfo.MenuId;
        if (prevClickedMenu != clickedMenu)
        {
            expandSubMenu = false;
            if (menuInfo.PageMenu != "" || menuInfo.MenuName == "Home")
            {
                hasPageName = true;
            }
            else
            {
                expandSubMenu = !expandSubMenu;
                hasPageName = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            expandSubMenu = !expandSubMenu;
        }

        prevClickedMenu = clickedMenu;
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        menuList = await MenuInfoService.GetMenuData();
    }
}
```

Também adicionei o serviço na classe Startup do projeto server:

```
using FirstBlazorFinal.Shared.Data;
using FirstBlazorFinal.Shared.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace FirstBlazorFinal.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddSingleton<MenuInfoService>();
...
```

Mas fiquei sem saber aonde configurar este serviço para o client enxergá-lo. Aonde posso verificar este erro?

Comment: Você consegue debugar o código e verificar se de fato essa service está sendo instanciada? PS.: o singleton não deveria ser configurado através da interface da classe?

Comment: Olá, ajustei o singleton, porém o erro persiste, não entendi ainda onde o erro ocorre, no _imports.razor (projeto client) incluí também o @using FirstBlazorFinal.Shared.Services que é onde está a classe de MenuInfoService que é utilizada no NavMenu.razor.

Comment: Você precisa fazer a injeção da dependência e não da classe. veja a documentação
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Tem um post no StackOverflow sobre isso. Isso te ajuda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027047/inputtext-requires-a-value-for-the-valueexpression-parameter